# How can I use R to get extract information from other dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have two dataframes where one is a cohort with each observation being one individual and the other a registry of visits with each observation being a visit.

I need to examine details about each persons visits (number of visits for a specific reason, time for first visit) but can't figure out how to achieve this.

Each individual in the first dataframe has a unique ID which also can be found in the second dataframe (but each ID can occur several times in the second dataframe).

```r
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:5)
df2 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5),
                  date = as.Date("2017-01-01") + 10*0:7
                  reason = c("A B C", "A E", "E F", "A D F","D","F A","B","D A"),
                  stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

Which brings another problem in that there can be multiple reasons for contact for each visit and these are separated by a blank space.

I've tried to come up with solutions for achieving this and figure that I could create new variables in the first dataframe that are generated from the data in the second dataframe to have all information needed for analysis in the same dataframe and then do my analysis.

Being quite new to R I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. Is this a reasonable way to go about the problem? How can it be done?

I've been able to successfully filter out the rows with the reasons I'm interested in and then join the two dataframes.

```r
combined <- df2 %>%
    filter(str_detect(reason,"B|E")) %>%
    distinct(id, .keep_all = TRUE %>%
    right_join(df1)
```

I now have the date and reason for contact for the first visit for any of the reasons I am interested in. What I also would like to have is a new variable with the number of visits with any of the reasons I am looking for. That is, count the rows where reason = A and/or E (for example).

I would like the output to be something like this:

```
id     firstdate     reasons     visits
1      2017-01-01    A B C       1
```

Which I managed to achieve with:

````r
df2 %>% 
  filter(str_detect(reason,"A|E")) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  tally(name="visits")
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this sample data:

```
# (BTW, it's standard practice to include this yourself in your question. 
#   This helps reduce the potential for misunderstandings about what you're starting from 
#   and where you're trying to get.)
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(ID = 1:3, stringsAsFactors = F)
df2 <- data.frame(ID = trunc(runif(6, 1, 5)),
                  date = as.Date("2019-01-01") + 40*0:5,
                  reason = c("A B C", "F", "B G", "C", "D E", "Z"),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
#> df1
#  ID
#1  1
#2  2
#3  3

#  ID       date reason
#1  2 2019-01-01  A B C
#2  2 2019-02-10      F
#3  3 2019-03-22    B G
#4  4 2019-05-01      C
#5  1 2019-06-10    D E
#6  4 2019-07-20      Z
```

We can use `left_join` from `dplyr` (in the `tidyverse` meta-package) and `separate_rows` from `tidyr` (also in `tidyverse`) to get the data in separate rows:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  left_join(df2) %>%    # This connects each matching row from df2 to df1
  separate_rows(reason) # This makes new rows for each separate entry in "reason"

#Joining, by = "ID"
#  ID       date reason
#1  1 2019-06-10      D
#2  1 2019-06-10      E
#3  2 2019-01-01      A
#4  2 2019-01-01      B
#5  2 2019-01-01      C
#6  2 2019-02-10      F
#7  3 2019-03-22      B
#8  3 2019-03-22      G
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know how to properly include the data in a good way but you've written a good representation of the data I'm working with. Should I update my question? I might not have been clear on what I want to achieve with it though. In df1 there should only be one row for each ID, but I want to add a column with a boolean for if there is a visit for a set of specific reasons, a column for which reason and a column with the time for the first visit for that reason.

Comment: It would be great to add more detail to your question. Ideally, it would show an example of useable input data, and example of the output you want, and any code you've tried that isn't satisfactory yet.

Comment: I'm specifically curious what kind of output you want for the situation where "there can be multiple reasons for contact for each visit." My answer puts each reason for each of the visits from the IDs in `df1` into a row. But perhaps you want to look at multiple reasons a different way?

Comment: I've updated the question but ran out of time so will add expected results later. Each `id` can only exist once in the combined dataframe or my analysis will be faulty. Ideally I would like a list for each `id` with all the reasons they've had and the numbers of visits for each reason but for my analysis the first of a set of reasons with date and total number of visits will suffice. Your answers so far has guided me quite far along the way and I'm really grateful for you taking time to help me!

Comment: Turns out you already pointed me in the right direction. If I do `df2 %>%
  separate_rows(reason) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(reason,"A|E")) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  tally()` I can get the number of visits for my reasons for each `id` and then do a join.